# how do I find paraphraphs with forgotten punctuation

Tags: regular-expression

Take the example file

```
this is line one of a paragraph
that continues here and finishes
with a full stop as it should.

Now we have a second paragraph
that continues in a new line, 
but the full stop is missing

I simply overlooked it, typing too fast.
```

How can I detect such errors? My naïve  grep approach

```
grep "^.*[a-zA-Z]$^$"  file.text
```

does *not* work (why?).

Comment: Rui, I rolled back you edit as it actually removed one of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '$NF !~ /[[:punct:]]$/' file
Now we have a second paragraph
that continues in a new line,
but the full stop is missing
```

This sets the record separator to a sequence of two newlines.  This means that each paragraph will be a record.  If the last field of the record (a word) does not end with a punctuation character (one of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``), then the paragraph is printed.

Instead of `[[:punct:]]` you could use a smaller character class like `[.!?]` if that is more appropriate.

If you want to include the paragraph number together with some decorative text in the output, use

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '$NF !~ /[[:punct:]]$/ { printf("ERROR (%d):\n%s\n", FNR, $0) }' file
ERROR (2):
Now we have a second paragraph
that continues in a new line,
but the full stop is missing
```

---

Your `grep` does not work since `grep` by default reads single lines at a time.  You cannot therefore expect to match anything after the `$` end of line anchor.

Answer (score 0):

An `sed` solution:

```
sed -n 'N;/[A-Za-z]\n$/P;D' file
```

This is a modification of the standard `sed 'N;P;D'`. It expects to reflect on the original regex that the OP is trying to `grep`.

Comment: This works as good as the next one. For some reason I cannot allow two answers. The second was easier to understand, so I voted for that one.

Comment: I don't really mind it, but note that you can transform any two-line long pattern you want to match by transform it in the way presented in this answer. Also you can upvote any answer that you find helpful besides accepting.